# Sandbox Login 'To access this page, you have to log in to Salesforce.' issue

Tags: sandbox

I am trying to login to Salesforce sandbox but am getting this issue. The error says 'To access this page, you have to log in to Salesforce'. Check below screenshot:

[image]

It was working on the sandbox an hour ago and it was working fine and somehow this happened.

Comment: Try to login clicking use custom domain. May be it's not letting login using test.salesforce.com

Comment: I did. Its the same error.

Comment: Have you checked status.salesforce.com to see if there are issues with the instance that you sandbox is on?  Are you able to login to any other sandboxes?

Comment: Can you log in through other methods, like workbench? What happens if you try to reset your password?

Comment: The easy(possible) fix could be: Try clearing browser cache memory and try logging in. I would even prefer to login using Chrome's Incognito window.

Comment: Instance is up and fine, i have tried workbench and sfdx, can't get authentication.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I tried clearing cache and even tried logging in from different system but the issue is the same.

Comment: You might need to consider opening a case with the Salesforce support.

Comment: That's what I did. Waiting for superfast Salesforce support.